# applescript: how to execute keystroke in several windows

Tags: ios, xcode, applescript, simulator

I need to execute some keystrokes by applescript (for example, `cmd + t` to create a new tab) in some app (for example, safari browser). So, I've written a code:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "Safari"
    set wList to every window whose visible is true

    repeat with app_window in wList
        log app_window
        set index of app_window to 1
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "t" using {command down}
        end tell
        delay (1)
    end repeat
end tell
```

I expect this code to open a new tab in each opened safari window. But actually, this code just opens `n` new tabs in the first active safari window, where `n` - is count of opened safari windows. It seems like I have a problem with focus changing in this line:

```
set index of app_window to 1
```

So, how to change focus correctly to execute keystrokes in each window?

**UPD**

Interesting thing - this code works correctly with Finder app (just replace Safari -> Finder), but it does not work with safari and ios simulators (Xcode)

**UPD**

Also, it doesn't work with Google Chrome - I'm getting the same behavior.

Comment: What is the reason not to use the Safari `make new tab` command?

Comment: new tab in Safari - is a simplified example :)

Comment: In real case I need to do more complicated thing in ios simulator. This code should work in different versions of simulator, where the option I need to switch can be located in different parts of the simulator menu. In some version this is `I/O -> Keyboard -> Toggle keyboard` and in another version this is `Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle keyboard`. But both versions have the same hotkey - `Cmd + K`, so I'm trying to call this hotkey.

Comment: You could use the the [`try`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-128973)-statement with an `on error` statement in there. You said there were two different ways the menu could be so if you `try` one and it fails, it will just try the other one. You could also nest such statements if you find there are more way the menu could be constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control indexes of windows directly, because property **index** is **read/only**. But you can do it with help of Safari.app:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set wList to every window whose visible is true
    repeat with aWindow in wList
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
        set miniaturized of aWindow to true
        delay 1
    end repeat
    repeat with aWindow in wList
        set miniaturized of aWindow to false
    end repeat
end tell
```

NOTE: you can use **visible** property instead of **miniaturized** property (no need delay):

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set wList to every window whose visible is true
    repeat with aWindow in wList
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
        set visible of aWindow to false
    end repeat
    repeat with aWindow in wList
        set visible of aWindow to true
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks! Your version with minimizing is working!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new `tab` to all the *windows* in **Safari**, then here is how it can be done:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    set myWindows to a reference to windows
    repeat with thisWindow in myWindows
        make new tab at end of tabs of thisWindow
    end repeat
end tell
```

**Notes:**

You can change `at end of tabs` to a different location, i.e,:

> [**at** location specifier] : The location at which to insert the object.

For example: `at beginning of tabs`

---

**Update to address comment:**

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set myWindows to ¬
        (windows whose visible is true)
    repeat with thisWindow in myWindows
        set winName to name of thisWindow
        my addNewTab(winName)
        --  # Do other stuff here.
        
    end repeat
end tell

to addNewTab(winName)
    tell application "System Events"
        perform action "AXRaise" of ¬
            window winName of process "Safari"
        delay 0.5
        keystroke "t" using command down
    end tell
end addNewTab
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: cool, thanks. But I'm interested exactly in keystroke calling. I have a problem with ios simulator (example with safari is synthetic) - I need to toggle the keyboard in the simulator and I can do it with cmd + K keystroke. Maybe do you know how to switch between windows and execute keystrokes in each of them?

Comment: Rostislav Shtanko, Please see the **Update to address comment:** section of my answer.

Comment: hm, your new example looks like an example from my question. I tried to execute it and got the same behaviour (`n` new tabs in one safari window). Did you launch this code on your mac?

Comment: @Rostislav Shtanko, Please see the **Update to address comment:** section, again, as I've resolved the issue with the previous _code_.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still creating `n` tabs in one window. But Robert Kniazidis version with minimizing is working.